# How to count result-row of a distinct query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, count, distinct

I want to count resulted row of this query - `Select Distinct JobURL From TblJobs`

When execute this query it's return `50` row. For count the resulted record row I used this query -

`Select Distinct Count(JobURL) AS RowIndex From TblJobs`, but it's give me result `450`

I don't want this output I want `50`.

Note : Table `TblJobs` have total 450 records.

How can I count resulted row number?

Comment: did you try `Select Count(Distinct JobURL)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT JobURL)` instead.

Comment: Exactly. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
select JobURL, count(*)
from TblJobs
group by JobURL;
```

**Or:**

```
select count(distinct JobURL)
from TblJobs;
```